# Move Ubuntu Desktop Icons to the right

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-icons

I'm looking for a way to move the Ubuntu Desktop Icons to the right without them getting put on the left.

Like in the Mac OS Format.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [what I've read](http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1204431), it doesn't look like this is possible. You'd have to manually put all your icons on the right side. New ones would still show up on the left.